# Element-UI : font-family differencies between components

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, element-ui

The font style/family is not standard between components.
For example :

- input vs textarea
- datatable vs datatable page-size popper dropdown
- the notification messages

How can I fix this in "element-ui" way ? 
Thank you.

Element-UI Version : 2.4.6

Answer (score 7):

I was facing a similar issue, if you are using webpack, one of the options is to add the following code when importing element UI:

```
import 'element-ui/lib/theme-chalk/reset.css'
```

You will find the original answer here:

https://forum.vuejs.org/t/elementui-styling-is-not-applied-to-new-webpack-element-ui-project/26194/9

Answer (score 1):

In my scenario I wanted to make a global change to the font-family.

On top of importing the above mentioned reset.css, as you mentioned some components i.e. `<input>`s, `<button>`s were still not behaving and inheriting the declared font-family (applied to say the `<body>`) and were falling back to browser defaults.

Digging around the element-ui GitHub issues, I found the following snippet which forces these missing elements to inherit their font-family, so a single font-family definition on the body will propagate to all components.  I insert this right after my body font-family definition.

```css
    button, 
    input, 
    select, 
    textarea {
            font-family: inherit;
            font-size: inherit;
            line-height: inherit;
            color: inherit;
        }
```

Taken from : https://github.com/ElemeFE/element/issues/150#issuecomment-249750366